# mysql select records in difference between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I just create a federated table (cron_task_sync) get the updated data from server. So now I want to update the outdated table (cron_task) in my local mysql database with that table.

Any sql can do this? I found there's a lot of limitation when I use mysql. For instance except cannot be used.

I am sure that that two table are in the same structure. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key, like `id`, you could use `not in`:

```
insert  into cron_task
        (id, col1, col2, col3, ...)
select  id
,       col1
,       col2
,       col3
from    cron_task_async
where   id not in
        (
        select  id
        from    cron_task
        )
```